# How to format a MacBook Air 2012?

Tags: macbook-pro

How to format a MacBook Air 2012? This laptop has no installation media.

Comment: Why do you want to format it at all?

Comment: To get rid of any personal data in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The MBA comes with a recovery partition already installed. Reboot and keep <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> pressed during boot until the Apple icon is displayed in screen. This boots into Recovery Mode allowing you to repair and/or reinstall the MBA from scratch.

See [OS X Lion: About Lion Recovery (HT4718)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) for details.

Comment: Additionally, make sure that when you are erasing your drive, add a secure erase by clicking "Security Options" on the Erase tab.

Comment: Or use FileVault 2 to encrypt the whole disk (something I recommend for laptops anyway)